# Joint between Asphalt Driveway and Block Foundation Sealant

Tags: foundation, waterproofing, sealant, asphalt

I want to put some type of sealant where the asphalt driveway meets the old cinderblock foundation on a house.  The gap is minimal if any, but I feel like it would be smart to put something. It is not thick enough to get a backer rod in, it goes from nothing to maybe 1/8th of an inch or less, so a sealant is ideal here.

The house gutters were a mess and most of the water was running right into the foundation, so water was pooling and I could see some water in the basement after the heaviest of rain. Now that I put new gutters all around I have not seen water since. However, I want to get this area where the 2 materials meet sealed while I am going through the process of painting the foundation block to make it look nicer.

What are some ideal sealants to use in this joint? I've seen some say use asphalt shingle tar that comes in the tube (Sikaflex type), but I don't want it to stay sticky or tacky. Is there a product I can use there that will fill the minor gap and will dry so it doesn't stay tacky and make a mess in the hot summer?

Comment: Roofing tar usually dries/skims over on the outside in time(a couple of weeks).  Will still be tacky if you dig into it, but the outside should feel dry.  That small amount should dry even faster and it is not in a place to bother people.

Answer (score 4):

The brand you mentioned (and other brands) make a self-leveling polyurethane horizontal joint sealant. It's applied from a standard or jumbo caulking gun, but once applied it flows and levels out like a very thick liquid to fill a gap, then cures but remains flexible.

It is not tacky once cured. They come in various curing speeds. Quicker is better for larger gaps so you don't lose too much to the depths. I've used two brands and they worked equally well.